# How to get site's name from WP API

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I'm trying to get WordPress website title using *javascript* and *WP API* plugin

I didn't find any example on how to get the site's name but I found the variable name under the entities section in the  [developer guide](http://wp-api.org/#entities)

```
function _updateTitle(documentTitle) {
    document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = 
        documentTitle + ' | '+ $http.get('wp-json/name');
}
```

The output string of `$http.get('wp-json/name')` is **[object Object]**

[image: Output]

Does anyone know how to use fix this?

Comment: So it’s an object, that probably has the value you are looking for set as a property – so log it to console, and see what it actually contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't get enough context. What's `$http`? What happens when you go to wp-json/name directly in your browser? Here's what I see:

```
[{
  "code":"json_no_route",
  "message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method"
}]
```

Here's a simple example to get you the title:

```
var siteName;
$.getJSON( "/wp-json", function( data ) {
  siteName = data.name;
});
```

Comment: thank you, I got it working like so: 

`function _updateTitle(documentTitle, pageTitle) {
  $http.get('wp-json').success(function( data ) {
   document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = documentTitle + ' | ' + data.name;
   WPService.pageTitle = pageTitle;
  });
    }`

Answer (score 1):

See more elegant solution here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/314767/94636
response will not contain extra data  like:

   `authentication: []
   namespaces: ["oembed/1.0", "akismet/v1", "acf/v3", "wp/v2"]
   routes: {/: {namespace: "", methods: ["GET"],…},…}
   timezone_string: ""
   ...
   _links: {help: [{href: "http://v2.wp-api.org/"}]}`